# Missing dependencies for dev branch

Tags: minko

I'm trying to get minko dev branch to work on linux `Mint 17.1` using `gcc 4.9.2`. While compiling the project created with the master branch I got some missing dependencies.

I had to install `glm 0.9.6.3-1` because the version in my repositories didn't have `matrix_decompose.hpp`.

Now, `Provider.hpp` includes `sparsehash/forward.h`. I couln't find any version of `sparsehash` with this file.

I find minko to be an incredibly good and practical library but it lacks documentation.
Also, the informations in the `README` and other files in the dev branch are wrong or outdated.

Two questions:

1. Where do I get the right sparsehash?
2. Is there a dependencies list somewhere?

Thank you for your efforts and help.

Comment: Why would you need a custom `glm` version? Everything is embedded in the framework (`framework/lib/glm`).

Comment: @WarrenSeine Actually, I don't know... the compiler just didn't find it and I didn't think about it. Going to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get minko dev branch to work on linux Mint 17.1 using
>   gcc 4.9.2. While compiling the project created with the master branch
>   I got some missing dependencies.
>
> I had to install glm 0.9.6.3-1 because the version in my repositories
>   didn't have matrix_decompose.hpp.

The 'master' branch does not use GLM (nor sparsehashmap). So you're probably on the 'dev' branch. Or worse, a mix of both. Try re-cloning the repo from scratch and properly checkout the 'dev' branch.

Also make sure you're following the documentation to build Minko:

- [Compiling the SDK for Windows](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_Windows.md)
- [Compiling the SDK for OS X](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_OS_X.md)
- [Compiling the SDK for Linux](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_Linux.md)
- [Compiling the SDK for HTML5](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_HTML5.md)
- [Compiling the SDK for iOS](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_iOS.md)
- [Compiling the SDK for Android](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_Android.md)

You should not have to download/setup any extra dependency (except some very specific stuff for Linux and the html-overlay plugin).

Comment: Thank you, apparently my download was corrupted and some files were missing entirely. I now managed to compile everything (expect for tests) and struggled a little to figure out the correct compilation command. Your skeleton file was not updated in the dev branch and still contains code and a Makefile relative to the master branch. I had to add the new includes using the Makefile from one of the examples. It's finally working now but I don't think this question will be usefull to others (because of the corrupted download) so I'm thinking about deleting it.

Comment: You never know what people might ask in the future: that's why it's always good to keep things like this. If you keep the question, please mark my answer as valid.